# Artisan::call error: Command "module:make Test" is not defined - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to call a artisan command from code. The command I want to execute is a command from the pingpong package and is as follows:

```
 php artisan module:make Test
```

I'm doing this with the following code:

```
Artisan::call('module:make Test');
```

The error I'm getting is: **Command "module:make Test" is not defined.**
While this is certainly a good command.

Parameters could be given with an array like:

```
Artisan::call('module:make', [
     'Test'
]);
```

But these parameters are only for flags I guess. Cause this command does nothing. No error. It just returns 0.

Same kind of question asked here:
https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules/issues/202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new module with pingpong package use:

```
Artisan::call('module:make', array(
    'name' => array('Test'),
));
```

Don't forget to place the code inside a route and not outside, like me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the name of the parameter is simply `name`, so you should be able to call it like this:

```
Artisan::call('module:make', [
     'name' => 'Test'
]);
```

Sources: https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules/blob/master/Commands/MakeCommand.php, http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code

Comment: Thank you for your command. I've tried that and it failed with the message invalid argument for foreach. Now I noticed in the file MakeCommand.php that it wants an array as value for the name parameter. So I did 'name' => array('Test'). This worked and made the folder, but... now I'm getting the error: **file_get_contents(/start.stub): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**. Not all files where added not one, only it created folders

Comment: That would be a separate error then, but I'm not familiar with PingPong so I don't know what it could be. At least you got past the first hurdle. :) Hope you can solve the next issue as well.

Comment: This error was incredibly stupid. I had that code in the routes.php file to quickly test it, but not inside a route. Now I placed it inside a route and it works... :D